# how to print gridview contents if it has data to print on more than a page in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, printing, datagridview

i have a gridview which has lots of data(from database) . and i want to take its Print out. the below code is working fine if i have only 1 page to print(i mean only 44 lines of records). if more than that rest part of the gridview content is not getting printed.

what are the changes required to allow multiple page printing if i have data to be printed on more than a page?

Anyone please help me....Hearty thanks in advance... my code attached below... expecting a quick and clear answer...

```
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

        Dim ColumnCount As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        Dim RowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount
        Dim CellTopPos As Integer = 1

        For Row = 0 To RowCount - 1

        Dim CellLeftPos As Integer = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left

           For Cell = 0 To ColumnCount - 1

           Dim CellValue As String = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Value.ToString()
           Dim CellWidth = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Width + 50
           Dim CellHeight = DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Height

           Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
           e.Graphics.DrawString(CellValue, New Font("Century Gothic", 10), Brush, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos)
           e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)

           CellLeftPos += CellWidth
           Next

           CellTopPos += DataGridView1.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Size.Height
          Next


    End sub



Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        preview.PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        preview.PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings
        preview.PrintPreviewControl1.Document = PrintDocument1()
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        preview.ShowDialog()

        AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintDocument1_PrintPage
    End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print on multiple page in VB on VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080061/print-on-multiple-page-in-vb-on-vs-2010)

Answer (score 0):

you have set e.HasMorePages to true if you want to print more pages and have to set it to false after completion. Take a look at [Printing a DataGridView](http://jeremycomer.com/blog/?p=64)

Comment: thanks sandeep for the reply. actually i am using VS2010. in this Allowpaging and Bind property is not available for gridview..... can u suggest me a way out?

Comment: i am not using any paging concept .actually i dont know what is  that actually.....

Comment: then what problem u are facing in print because you should be able to print all the rows you have in DataGridView1.

Comment: see ..i have 100rows in gridview. but one page can accomodate only 51 lines while printing.so the rest of the lines are supposed to be printed on the next page(page2). this is not happening now.it is printing only the first 51 lines of the grid. i want to get the print out of all rows even if i have huge number of rows.

Comment: check blog mentioned in answer